# Windows function "NetUserChangePassword" is no longer working under Windows 10 (worked under Windows 7)

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, networking

I am using the following code sample from the MSDN page to change the network password of a user (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netuserchangepassword):

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif
#pragma comment(lib, "netapi32.lib")

#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h> 
#include <lm.h>

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
   DWORD dwError = 0;
   NET_API_STATUS nStatus;
   //
   // All parameters are required.
   //
   if (argc != 5)
   {
      fwprintf(stderr, L"Usage: %s \\\\ServerName UserName OldPassword NewPassword\n", argv[0]);
      exit(1);
   }
   //
   // Call the NetUserChangePassword function.
   //
   nStatus = NetUserChangePassword(argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], argv[4]);
   //
   // If the call succeeds, inform the user.
   //
   if (nStatus == NERR_Success)
      fwprintf(stderr, L"User password has been changed successfully\n");
   //
   // Otherwise, print the system error.
   //
   else
      fprintf(stderr, "A system error has occurred: %d\n", nStatus);

   return 0;
}
```

Under Windows 7 it is possible to use this program to change the password of a user. Example:

```
> NetUserChangePassword.exe \\192.168.1.2 TestUser TestPassword TestPassword  
> User password has been changed successfully
```

Under Windows 10 the exact same program is no longer working:

```
> NetUserChangePassword.exe \\192.168.1.2 TestUser TestPassword TestPassword 
> A system error has occurred: 5
```

The security settings on both machines (Win7 & Win10) are identical and the firewall is turned off.
Ideas on how to fix this problem would be highly appreciated!

Comment: `5` is `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` - you probably need an elevated context

Comment: I have added every single privilege that can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/privilege-constants (including SE_CHANGE_NOTIFY_NAME) and none of them changed the outcome.
I also ran the program as administrator.

Comment: We can't tell you why you don't have privileges on your network to change the password under Windows 10. The error message says `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`, which means the code is indicating that you don't have access to change the password on the remote machine. Have you spoken to your IT department?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are programming for Active Directory, you may be able to call [`IADsUser::ChangePassword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iadsuser-changepassword) method to achieve the same result you can achieve by calling `NetUserChangePassword` function.

If an application calls the NetUserChangePassword function on a domain controller that is running Active Directory, the default ACL permits only **Domain Admins** and **Account Operators** to call this function.

On a member server or workstation, only **Administrators** and **Power Users** can call this function.

**A user** can change his or her own password.

In some cases, the process that calls the NetUserChangePassword function must also have the **SE_CHANGE_NOTIFY_NAME** privilege enabled.

So there are two information you need to check:

1. If you are using Active Directory or not?
2. If the account your program running as meets required privilege or not? For example, to find what role the account is playing as you can use the following code sample (in C#). Refer to [`WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal.isinrole?view=netframework-4.8) method.

   ```
       AppDomain myDomain = Thread.GetDomain();

       myDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
       WindowsPrincipal myPrincipal = (WindowsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
       Console.WriteLine("{0} belongs to: ", myPrincipal.Identity.Name.ToString());

       Console.WriteLine("{0}? {1}.", "Domain Admins",
          myPrincipal.IsInRole("Domain Admins"));

       Console.WriteLine("{0}? {1}.", "AccountOperator",
          myPrincipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.AccountOperator));

       Console.WriteLine("{0}? {1}.", "Administrators",
          myPrincipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator));

       Console.WriteLine("{0}? {1}.", "PowerUser",
          myPrincipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.PowerUser));
   ```